# What is the difference between Gzip and SZ error-bounded Lossy compression

Tags: gzip

I'm asking on the  difference between Gzip and SZ error-bounded lossy compression and is there any relation between these compressors?

Answer (score 0):

SZ compressor is lossy, Gzip, lossless. Then the first can obtain better compression ratio.

Comment: Are these algorithms dependent on deflate algorithm ?

Comment: Gzip is based on deflate which is a lossless algorithm. Since SZ is lossy, their algorithms are different, even if they may borrow some ideas (Huffman coding…). SZ uses 2nd-order regression and 2nd-order Lorenzo predictors to improve the prediction accuracy significantly. Then it may be similar to Flac or other audio compression algorithm.